# Catch 404 exception from StaticFileModule in IIS7 integrated pipeline mode

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis-7, http-status-code-404

Does anyone know if there is a good programatic way (not using the CustomError settings) to catch / handle an 404 error coming from the StaticFileModule in integrated pipeline mode on a IIS7?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is it for performance reasons? Is it for custom routing purposes?

Comment: I needed a way to show a custom 404 page, and not a static html/aspx file but a dynamic selected page from a CMS framework.

Comment: Are you running in Integrated or Classic mode? I assume Classic mode because IIS7 custom error pages work fine with static files in Integrated mode. If Classic, can you switch to Integrated mode or does your application not work correctly in that mode?

Comment: As the question says :) i'm already in integrated mode, and I need to show a "dynamic" page not a defined page in web.config. This is realy an old problem and I solved it some other way, so if you don't now directly how to solve it feel free to let it go :)

Comment: You want dynamic code to run, but state that it must be processed by the StaticFileModule. That is what is confusing us. The whole point of the StaticFileModule is to be a simple file dump, not something that runs dynamic code. I think your assumption that you need StaticFileModule is wrong. Get rid of that requirement, and with Integrated mode, you'll have no problem using the built-in ASP.NET web.config customer error solution.

Comment: Im sorry if the question was unclear, but what I was looking for was a progrmatically way to "overide" or hook into when the static file handler (in integrated mode) was throwing / causing a 404.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried overriding the HttpApplication.Error event in your Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Error (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpException httpException = Context.Error as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode ())
            {
                case 404:
                    // do stuff here
                    //Server.ClearError ();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think @bang is looking for a solution that doesn't run in the application .Net process, but as a way to configure or adjust it while running in the StaticFileModule. (Though _why_ he wants to do that is unclear.)